# Mathematical formulas: parsing and canonical *programming* form

Tags: haskell, math, tex

**Is there any conventional format to represent a mathematical formula, that could be read by a computer?**

I'm working on some mathematical problems, and have some kind of TDD approach to it. Every time I get stuck in a proof (or simply that I have no proof yet, but some intuition of what the result should be), I tend to write a little program to check that everything so far behaves as I'm thinking it does. I usually write a Haskell function for some intermediary result in my proof, play with it through `GHCi` until I'm convinced I'm still going in the right direction.

My absolute ideal would be to have some canonical form for math formulas which I could, using some tool, both output to LaTeX and Haskell. I could run QuickTest on it, and if a step is wrong, it would tell me. LaTeX's mathematical notations are actually pretty close to a *canonical* form, though a lot is inferred by the reader (you don't want to explicitly write **every** parentheses).

This ideal tool seems too good to be true; rather, what would be the correct way to spell out a mathematical formula for a computer, possibly parsing it as well? While looking around, I saw a lot for simple formulas using solely `*`,`+`,`-`,`/` and the like. Nothing encompassing things like sums (e.g. over sets), derivatives, all the "cool" stuff. Moreover, the output of such parsers are mostly used to calculate a result, giving some values for the variables; not for translating it to other languages (language agnostic, I guess). It seems like something like this should either already exist, or there should be a good reason why not. Which one did I miss?

Comment: https://github.com/leftaroundabout/Symbolic-math-HaTeX. It's not really finished and I haven't worked on it in a while, but it demonstrates “both output to LaTeX and Haskell” is not so far-fetched: write the formulas as more or less ordinary Haskell code, and let the `MathematicalLaTeXT_` eDSL monad produce LaTeX code from it.

Comment: There's a lot of prior work in this area, see *Maple* or *Mathematica* or *Sage* or one of many other *computer-algebra systems*.  These cover part of the ground you are interested in exploring.  But I think you should let go of the idea of their being one true canonical form -- my memory grows dim but I recall there being a fundamental theorem of mathematical logic that there isn't, and can't be, a single canonical form to represent any expression of a system such as *mathematics*.  Think `x^2-1` *vs* `(x+1)(x-1)`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for your input. What you pointed out with `f1(x) = x^2-1` vs `f2(x) = (x+1)(x-1)` is not an issue, quite the opposite: once you have them both spelled out in their own *canonical* form, you could then check that both `f1` and `f2` actually output the same result for any `x`. My own memory grows dim in regards to *Mathematica* and the like, so it's time for a refresher.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I like the idea behind HaTeX and your project (I actually recently started working on a Ruby equivalent). I think your comment could definitely be considered as an (at least partial) answer.

Comment: @NicolasMattia: well, let's first see whether somebody has a _full_ answer!

Answer (score 4):

The standard computer representation of mathematical notation is [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/). Note that it includes both [Presentation MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/chapter3.html), which represents the way mathematical expressions are written and can be [converted to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85643/5584), and [Content MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter4.html) which is intended to represent the *meaning* of expressions and is what you'd need for translation to Haskell or another programming language (but I don't know of any tool which does such translation).

Of course, you wouldn't want to write (either flavor of) MathML manually; there are some editors which produce it, but I can't recommend one.

Otherwise, [OpenMath](http://www.openmath.org/overview/index.html) could be an option. It seems to be oriented exactly towards people "working with mathematics on computer".

Comment: Just so nobady gets disappointed upon finding out: the ML in MathML has nothing to do with [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_%28programming_language%29), but with XML.

Comment: That Content MathML is very interesting. While reading about it I've also come across OpenMath, which seems to have even more range. I'll keep looking and see if any such translation tool exists; otherwise I guess it's time to write one.

Comment: @NicolasMattia I think your edit should be a separate answer; you _are_ allowed to answer your own questions.